# in my angular2 code i want to update value of form but my click function is not working

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

In my angular2 code I want to update value of form but my click function is not working.

My code is:

```
<div *ngIf="payLoad" class="form-row">    
    <li (click)="select()">{{payLoad}}</li>   
</div>
```

and my main component is:

```
select(payLoad) {     
    this.form.value.external_id=payLoad;   
}    

onSubmit()  {
    if (this.form.valid) {
        for(let fm in this.form.value) { 
            if(fm == 'external_id') {
                this.payLoad=this.form.value.external_id;
            }   
            if(fm == 'lastname') {
                this.payLoad1=this.form.value.lastname; 
            }
            if(fm == 'email') { 
                this.payLoad2=this.form.value.email;
            } 
            if(fm == 'gender') { 
                this.payLoad3=this.form.value.gender;
            } 
            if(fm=='brave'){ 
                this.payLoad4=this.form.value.brave;
            }  
            if(fm=='role') { 
                this.payLoad5=this.form.value.role; 
            } 
            if(fm=='status') {
                this.payLoad6=this.form.value.status;           
            }       
        }            
    }     
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We try to maintain some quality here. Please clean up the mess. The code in your question is unreadable.

Comment: Please read: [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

In Angular2, `FormGroup`s only expose its value through `.value`, you cannot update a `FormGroup`'s value through it.
You need to either use `.setValue(value)` or `.patchValue(value)`.

- Use `.setValue(value)` if you want to set the entire group's value using one object (it must match the schema of your `FormGroup`.
- Use `.patchValue(value)` if you want to set only a subset of the group's values using a partial object matching the `FormGroup`'s schema.